# Firebase and AngularFire error in ng-repeat only in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, firebase, angularfire

I have an app that is using angular and firebase.  It makes a call to my firebase url and does a simple ng-repeat of the 2 items in the object returned.

The app works great in every browser except Internet Explorer 8.  I tested it in IE 8 often and it was working.  Not that I have launched it, sometime in the last few days it began receiving this error. I have made changes in the app over this time, but nothing in my mind that would change the way IE8 would render it.

The error in IE8 is simply:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'artists' of undefined or null reference
firebase.js, line 1 character 28

I have simplified the code down to the basics and I still get the error.

You can see below, artists is the name of the object in $scope.xmatch that I am trying to repeat with ng-repeat.  I ahve to get this working, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

app.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('ipremiosApp', ['firebase']).config
}).call(this);
```

global.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('ipremiosApp').controller('GlobalCtrl',['$scope','$timeout',    function($scope, $timeout) {
}]);

angular.module('ipremiosApp').controller('MatchCtrl',['$scope','$timeout','$routeParams','angularFire', function($scope,$timeout,$routeParams,angularFire) {

  var url = 'https://my.firebaseio.com/myfirebase';
  $scope.xmatch = angularFire(new Firebase(url), $scope, 'xmatch');

}]);
}).call(this);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="ipremiosApp" data-ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <div class="main-body match-page" data-ng-controller="MatchCtrl">
    <div id="test" class="artist" data-ng-repeat="artist in xmatch.artists | orderBy: 'votes':true">
    {{artist.name}}
  </div>
</div>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-fire/angularfire.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/global.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug was introduced into angularFire in [this commit](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/commit/b75e556da74b1970eef58ba9ca3c87ce5b063d60) which affects IE 8 only. I've [filed an issue here](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/141).

The problem stems from the fact that `$scope.xmatch` is not declared before angularFire() is initalized. You can work around this problem, until a fix is released, by declaring it to an empty object like so:

```
new Firebase(url).child('test').set('happy');
$scope.xmatch = {};
angularFire(new Firebase(url), $scope, 'xmatch');
```

Also, on a side note, you had a subtle bug in your code that could bite you later. You've accidentally set $scope.xmatch to the returned value (a promise) from angularFire:

```
// don't do this
$scope.xmatch = angularFire(new Firebase(url), $scope, 'xmatch');
```

It seemed to work out here without any negative effects, because you haven't used $scope.xmatch for anything before the data arrives from Firebase and overwrites the bad declaration, but you certainly don't want that hash set to a promise value :)

Comment: Thanks.  I will give this a try.  And thanks for pointing out the other bug.  I knew that wasn't quite.